# Turn textfield into multiline

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm in need of turning a text field into multiline and store each line as a variable to use in some mathematic equations. Each line will only hold numbers with no decimals. Is this possible with iOS or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Why not a text view or a table view?

Comment: Which would be better suited for numeric input so the user could use carriage return to keep entering figures? And could still store each line as a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your concerns, using a text field is suitable for entry but not the listing display. A table view is best for a listing display. Use each UI item where, and how, it's most appropriate.

Comment: I see where you are going with that. I think my best option may be to create a web version of this and make a simple browser app to use it. I need to make this across a couple of platforms and that may make life easier in the long run. Thank you for your input everyone!

Answer (score 0):

For more then one line you **can't** use textfield,  better you use UITtextView.

But according to your problem you can take more then one textfield with with no boarder and take any common background image so that you can easily store value of each lines.
may b this can solve your problem.

Comment: The multiple text field  issue is how many do I add. Sometimes a user will enter in 2-3 lines and other times  could add 5-10.

Comment: Then better u use textview and fetch component by separator like new line character or something.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with `UITextField`. Better option is to use multiple `UITextField` and set background image for each text field to a custom image to make them appear merged, with a slight border style adjustment, they will appear to user as one component, and then you can manage each line as a separate equation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have more then one line in a `UITextField`. I think what you would be looking for is instead a `UITextView`. You can have as many lines as you wish with those. If you're dead-set against a text view, you could do is create multiple text fields and adjust the border style, making them transparent.

Comment: I'm not dead set on a text field. I can live with text view but don't know how to store each line as a variable

Comment: @DerekHutchinson I would go with using transparent UITextFields then, it would probably make life easier for storing variables.